# HTML Tags stripped using tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Latest version of tinyMCE is stripping my embed tags, and javascript when I use it. I tried setting the verify_html flag to false without any luck. Here is my config js for tinyMCE, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**Update**: I am positive it is not a server side issue. I used a plain textarea without tinymce loaded and it worked perfectly. It is tinyMCE doing the stripping.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins:
safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,
insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,
fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups",
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    verify_html : false,


    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1:     
    bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,
justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen|,forecolor,
backcolor,code",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: 
    "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,
outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,advhr",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: 
"tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    height: "500px",

    // Example word content CSS (should be your site CSS) this one removes paragraph
   // margins
    content_css: "content/word.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values: {
        username: "Some User",
        staffid: "991234"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update #2**:

After doing some more digging, you ought to try the following.

Set:

```
media_strict: false
```

And set the settings for the `<embed>` tag:

```
+'embed[width|height|name|flashvars|src|bgcolor|align|play|loop|quality|allowscriptaccess|type|pluginspage]'
```

Source ([MoxieCode Forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=15991))

---

**Update**:

You're setting `extended_valid_elements`, but not setting [valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements)?:

```
valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

`extended_valid_elements` is used for the current ruleset. But `valid_elements` allows you to actually create that ruleset.

---

**Old Answer**:

Are you sure it's TinyMCE doing it, and not whatever is parsing the server-side request?

If you're using ASP.NET, make sure `ValidateRequest="False"` is set for the page.  If you're using ASP.NET MVC, then you'll need to put the following above the controller action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Make sure you're at least using a [whitelist to keep bad stuff out](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html), though.