# HTML tags saved to database as HTML entities

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, tinymce

I am using this code to update values in a database:

```
function text_save( $page_name, $page_title, $page_text ) {

    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "abcd";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "thedatabase";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

    // Check connection
    if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
        die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
    }

    $page_content = $page_text;

    $sql = "UPDATE text SET page_title=?, page_text=? WHERE text_name=?";

    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );

    // check whether the prepare() succeeded
    if ( $stmt === false ) {    
        trigger_error( $this->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR );
    }

    $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $page_title, $page_content, $page_name );

    $stmt->execute();

    print '<p>Text saved</p>';

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

The variable `$page_text` is set from a tinymce text area on a form submission and is HTML content.

If I var_dump the value of `$page_text`, it comes out as:
`string(23) "<p>test</p>"`

When the `$page_content` data is saved to the database, it is saved as:

```
&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;
```

However, if I manually set the value of `$page_content` to
    `<p>test</p>,`

e.g. `$page_content = "<p>test</p>";` instead of 
`$page_content = $page_text;`

it is saved to the database as:

```
<p>test</p>
```

I need the HTML to be saved to the database without being converted to HTML entities i.e. as `<p>test</p>` not `&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;`?

**This is what I have tried so far:**

Setting the page to utf8 - `<meta charset="utf-8" />`,

setting the form to utf8 - `accept-charset="UTF-8"`,

setting the connection to utf8 - `mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");`

setting the tinymce init with - `entity_encoding : "raw"`

What am I doing wrong here, and why does the HTML string save correctly when I manually set the variable rather than using the form variable value (which seems to be identical)?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Try <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: And put <!DOCTYPE html> above your <html>

Comment: Thanks Micaela, I have just tried adding the full meta tag as suggested but no luck unfortunately. I already had <!DOCTYPE html> on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the html_entity_decode function,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

```
$page_content = html_entity_decode($page_text);
```

Be careful about injections and such.

Comment: Yes, it was the tinymce editor, thanks @wilo087! Even though the var_dump showed string(23) "<p>test</p>", the HTML had been converted to entities, I should have picked up on the string(23) which relates to the extra entity characters.  html_entity_decode fixed it up for me, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the editor.

can you try to print the value of $page_content before insert into database and show us?

too, see this post.
[HTML Tags stripped using tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982191/html-tags-stripped-using-tinymce)